# is there a Memcached equivalent written in c#?

Tags: c#, memcached

is there a Memcached equivalent written in c# ? open source maybe ?

Comment: Are you looking for a distributed in-memory cache written in C#, or for a C# client API to interact with memcached.

Comment: @jim : yes i'm looking for a distributed in-memory cache written in C# i know about the api for memcached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is open source:

http://www.codeplex.com/SharedCache

Comment: note this is not compatible with memcached (if that's what Yassir meant by "equivalent")

Comment: @zvolkov: I suspect that Yassir meant "equivalent" when using the word "equivalent" ;)

Comment: @Anthony: actually i meant it :) i want a distributed in-memory cache system written in managed code

Answer (score 6):

There is Microsoft's upcoming distributed caching framework code named [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx)

I don't know how it will be licensed when released.

Answer (score 2):

We are using MemCached in our .net applications and so far we are pretty happy. As to Velocity we considered it as an option. It is supposed to be much more powerful than memcached, but we decided against using it because it is too new (read potentially unstable), and also because the licensing of the released version is unknown at this time

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to *invoke* memcached itself from C#, check out [this list of clients](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients).